# What are the courses (other than mathematics) that are necessary to understand mathematics itself?

Tags: soft-question, education, learning

Physicists, computer scientists, engineers, (and many others) all study maths subjects beside their fields, because maths plays a critical role to understand such fields and to achieve required accuracy of calculations needed.

But, what are the courses that are necessary to understand mathematics itself?

Logic course could be one of them to understand and agree with the mathematical proofs.

I am not specifying any branch of maths, but in general, I believe there must be some important course that play a significant role to understand maths (not only proofs).

I wish you can suggest me.

---

Your help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Logic, at least necessary for understanding proofs, is taught in math courses.

Comment: Philosophy?  ....." I believe there must be some important course that play a significant role to understand maths "  Why?  Then what would be basic to studying *that* field.  .... Or is it turtles all the way down?... I'm not going to say I'm right and you are wrong but.... perhaps mathematics in its abstract form was *invented* solely *to* be the basis of all those disciplines and it is intrinsic in its creation that it *was* successful in being such a basis.   ... (Do I believe that?  Ask me again when the wind is southerly.)

Comment: Philosophy. Asking questions like, “why has it turned out that abstract mathematical models represent real life things?” and in “why” questions about mathematical truths in general- I would consider these to be more “fundamental” than mathematics itself.

Comment: To UNDERSTAND physics you need no math , you need math to DESCRIBE the phenomenons quantitative AFTER you have understood what is going on. In modern physics (in particular astronomy) this important fact has unfortunately been forgotten with catastrophical consequences.